# How to calculate average JS distance between two rows for each group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (see below sample) as below. I would like to calculate the average distance between each unordered pair for each firm each quarter. *Edit: the actual dataframe has over 700,000 rows. If you know a fast solution, that would be greatly appreciated!

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 'facebook', 2021_01], [0.4, 0.5, 0, 'facebook', 2021_01], [0.2, 0.4, 0.3,'facebook', 2021_01],[0.3, 0.1, 0.2,'facebook', 2021_02],
[0.4, 0.2, 0.2,'facebook', 2021_02],[0.2, 0.4, 0.2,'facebook', 2021_02],[0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 'apple', 2021_01], [0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 'apple', 2021_01], [0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 'apple', 2021_01], 
[0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 'apple', 2021_02],[0.2, 0.2, 0.9, 'apple', 2021_02],[0.2, 0.6, 0.5, 'apple', 2021_02]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c','firm','quarter_year'])
```

[image]

To calculate the distance between unordered pairs regardless of firm or quarter in the FULL dataframe, I will use Jenson-Shannon Divergence Score from scipy as below:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import jensenshannon as js    

prob=df.iloc[:, 0:3]
output = []
for i,j in combinations(df.index.tolist(),2 ):  #update df 
    # J-S for liwc 
    sim_cult = js(prob.loc[i], prob.loc[j])
    output.append([i, j, sim_cult])
```

However, I have a hard time finding a way to add `groupby(['firm','quarter_year'])` function to the above loop. In essence, I'd like to get another column with the Average Divergence Score per company per quarter. For example, for facebook in 202101, the average will be based on the distance between

> row0, row1, and row2

.

How do I run the above code but for each group (firm + quarter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap the code to compute the average distance in a function, and apply it to your dataframe after grouping.

```
def mean_js_dist(grp):
    prob=grp.iloc[:, 0:3]
    output = []
    for i,j in combinations(grp.index.tolist(),2 ):  
        sim_cult = js(prob.loc[i], prob.loc[j])
        output.append([i, j, sim_cult])
    return np.mean(np.array(output), axis=0)

df.groupby(['firm','quarter_year']).apply(mean_js_dist)
```

This is the general idea, but I'm not sure exactly what format you want the output in, or how you want to handle the three return values. Feel free to specify in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! The final output would be an additional column - 'avg_distance' appended to each row in the original data frame.

Comment: but how do you want to handle the three values from a, b, and c? three separate columns?

Comment: Would like to calculate the group average of the JS distance output. For example, the first three rows will have the same average JS value since they share the same firm and same quarter_year.